# Broadcom wireless card only works when the power is plugged in

Tags: wireless, hardware, drivers, dell, broadcom

I've a Dell, with a Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g wireless card. It works well when the laptop is plugged to the power suply, but when it's with battery it doesn't work well.

Do you know why is this?

Comment: Does the wifi stop working or does it work badly? What is the output of `sudo rfkill`? does it show the wifi as switched off?

Comment: I have this same problem.  It only happens at one coffee shop.  I can connect to the router, but on battery power websites will not load, or they load extremely slowly.  This has only happened recently, however, so I assume their router configuration is involved.  I have the BCM4321 card and rfkill doesn't show the wifi as switched off.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`pm-powersave` helps your battery life by powering down stuff (including your wireless) when AC power goes away. See [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery)

Answer (score 0):

b43 seems to not support power management (at least out of the box). Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76310/broadcom-b43-power-management/81634#81634. And, probably, this one: [Dell Vostro hangs/freezes randomly after AC power or wifi swtiched off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65036/dell-vostron-hangs-freezes-randomly-after-ac-power-or-wifi-swtiched-off/81677#81677). Hope this helps.